# Reshape tensor acording to assignment batch vector

Tags: python

So, I have this tensor:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6],
                  [7,8],
                  [9,0]])
```

and this assignment vector `vec` for every elem in `x`,

```
vec = torch.tensor([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2])
```

I need to make list of tensors this way

```
l =  [torch.tensor([[1,2],
                    [3,4],
                    [5,6]]),
      torch.tensor([[7,8]]),
      torch.tensor([[9,0]])]
```

How can I do it? 6 zeros means 6 elem in tensor 0. 2 ones means 2 elem in tensor 1. etc. Number of columns should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you need is `ravel`

Example:

```py
x = torch.tensor([[1,2],
                  [3,4],
                  [5,6],
                  [7,8],
                  [9,0]])
torch.ravel(x)
```

Output:

```
tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Doc:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.ravel.html

Comment: It's not what I asked for. i dont need it flattened. i need it specific shape. but thank you

Comment: my question was incorect in first place. i revisited it.